# How to use ffmpeg_kit_flutter to merge two videos in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, video, ffmpeg, video-processing

i want to merge an intro.mp4 (located in the assets folder of my project) video with the cameraRecord Output video (let's say output.mp4)

i tried this (code below) but it gives a bad result (the output video is side by side not sequential ) also it didn't work with the assets folder i think all the paths should come from the device and not from the project (assets ...)

```
Future<void> mergeRecordWithIntro(String outputPath, String videoPath) async {
emit(MergeVideoLoading());
const String introPath = 'assets/logo.mp4';
const filter =
    " [0:v]scale=480:640,setsar=1[l];[1:v]scale=480:640,setsar=1[r];[l][r]hstack;[0][1]amix -vsync 0 ";

await FFmpegKit.execute(
        '-y -i $videoPath -i $videoPath -filter_complex $filter $outputPath')
        
    .then((value) async {
  final returnCode = await value.getReturnCode();

  if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(returnCode)) {
    GallerySaver.saveVideo(outputPath);
    emit(MergeVideoSucces());
  } else if (ReturnCode.isCancel(returnCode)) {
    emit(MergeVideoError());
  }
});
```

this is my updates log [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HG82S.png) using this command :

```
-y -i $firstVideoPath -i $secondVideoPath -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=480:640[v0];[1:v]scale=480:640[v1];[v0][0:a][v1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" $outputPath
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this command worked for me the only problem is the output video quality is very low so... !! :

```
-y -i $firstVideoPath -i $videoPath -r 24000/1001 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1080:1920[v0];[1:v]scale=1080:1920[v1];[v0][0:a][v1][1:a]concat=n=2:v =1:a=1[outv][outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" -vsync 2 $outputPath
```

Answer (score 0):

First, save the video in the project's assets folder to a temporary folder and use the path there.

```dart
final byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/logo.mp4');
final file = await File('${Directory.systemTemp.path}${path.replaceAll('assets', '')}').create();
await file.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer.asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));
final firstVideoPath = file.path;
```

Next, the command to merge videos is `concat`, so fix it. *If you have a different resolution or codec, you may need to fix it.

```dart
await FFmpegKit.execute('-y -i "concat:$firstVideoPath|$secondVideoPath" -c copy $outputPath')
```

Finally, use the [gal package](https://pub.dev/packages/gal)  instead of the gallery_saver, which is already two years out of maintenance.

```dart
await Gal.putVideo($outputPath);
```

Comment: i tried your solution thank you .I managed to get the asset video but when i execute the command (FFmpeg.execute )the result is only intro video, it doesn't merge it with the second video  knowing that am passing the  stopRecord output from camera plugin as path for secondVideoPath  any suggestions ?

Comment: i think the problem is in the videos passed as arguments to the FFmpeg command .They have different resolution and different codec.  any solution to solve that ?

Comment: @AbderrahmanBelhadj Can you try this command?
`-y -i $firstVideoPath -i $secondVideoPath -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=480:640[v0];[1:v]scale=480:640[v1];[v0][0:a][v1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" $outputPath`

If this doesn't work, it may be a codec issue, check the [wiki](https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit/wiki/Packages) to see if you need the package.

Comment: @AbderrahmanBelhadj This allows you to get a log of the session so you can examine what is failing in more detail.
`FFmpegKitConfig.enableLogCallback((log) {
  final message = log.getMessage();
  print(message);
});`

Comment: i tried the command, it gives a 'conversion failed' log message  you can see the full log (see the screenShot )

Comment: @AbderrahmanBelhadj How about using the `-vsync 2` command
`-y -i $firstVideoPath -i $secondVideoPath -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=480:640[v0];[1:v]scale=480:640[v1];[v0][0:a][v1][1:a]concat=n=2:v =1:a=1[outv][outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" -vsync 2 $outputPath.
`

Comment: same problem... i think it's because the recorded video is at a very hight resolution  !

Comment: @AbderrahmanBelhadj Looking at the logs, it appears that multiple errors are occurring. As a result of using the `vsync` command, the "Please consider specifying a lower framerate, a different muxer or setting vsync/fps mode to vfr" has disappeared?

Comment: yes that error has disappeared only this remains : timebase 1/1000000 not supported by MPEG 4 standard, the maximum admitted value for the timebase denominator is 65535
I/flutter (31706): FFmpeg log message:Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

Comment: this command worked for me  the problem is the output video quality is very low : `-y -i $firstVideoPath -i $videoPath -r 24000/1001 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1080:1920[v0];[1:v]scale=1080:1920[v1];[v0][0:a][v1][1:a]concat=n=2:v =1:a=1[outv][outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" -vsync 2 $outputPath`

Comment: @AbderrahmanBelhadj OK. let's specify the frame rate. `-y -i $firstVideoPath -i $secondVideoPath -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=480:640, fps=30[v0];[1:v]scale=480:640, fps=30[v1];[v0][0:a][v1][1: a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" $outputPath`

Comment: @AbderrahmanBelhadj  And specify the `scale` as desired if necessary.

Comment: i changed the scale to 1080*1920 but the output result still has a very low quality !

Comment: @AbderrahmanBelhadj What are the results of this command?
`-y -i $firstVideoPath -i $secondVideoPath -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=480:640, fps=30[v0];[1:v]scale=480:640, fps=30[v1];[v0][0:a][v1][1: a ]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" $outputPath`
(And specify the scale as desired if necessary)

Comment: i'm getting a very low quality output ! (pixelated video,not high resolution ), any idea why ?

Comment: @AbderrahmanBelhadj What is the resolution of each video? The `scale=480:640` part of the above command needs to be changed to something more suitable.